# React/Webpack: How to transform relative resource URLs if production build runs under alias path?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I've setup an app using Create React App that needs to be deployed to a production server where the app runs unter an alias path, i.e.

http://server.com/alias/

instead of

http://server.com

I am also using the Redux version of React Router. My problem is that the image URLs are not translated correctly. If I use absolute paths, the images won't be found since the server looks for them under root. If I use relative paths, the images won't be found if React Router modifies the URL to point to a deeper location than /alias, e.g. /alias/search.

After doing an "eject" for Create React App, I saw that I can set a "homepage" path using package.json. This solved the problem that Webpack has to set the alias correctly when including the JavaScript and CSS files in the main index page.

But this option won't tell React to apply the alias to resources which are included by  links. Is there any plugin that will tell React to prepend my alias to all links without having to hard-code them in the React code?

Plus, I couldn't find an option yet to tell React Router that it should also use the alias for all links. At the moment, I am setting them hard-coded in the routes. This is working fine, bit is also sub-optimal.

Answer (score -1):

When building for production set the [publicpath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#output-publicpath) option under output properties

```
module.exports = { 
    //....
    output : {
       publicPath: "/alias/"
    }
    // additional configuration
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what the homePath of React Create App already sets. However, this only transforms the paths for including the minified .js and .css files in index.html. It does *not* transform any asset (image, font) urls referenced in my components, nor does it tell ReactRouter that the routes are located under the alias.